# How do I set focus on my input on page load?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular application with a 'slider' component that loads 3 child components using `ng-content`. The first child component contains a form and I want to set the focus on the first field on page load. I believe I've setup ViewChild correctly to reference the nativeElement, and this functionality seems to work when I call the focus manually. However I cannot get the focus to work on the initial page load.

I suspect it's something to do with the child component being loaded with `ng-content` but I can't figure out a solution.

here is the control in my component template:

```
<label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
     required
     [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
     #name="ngModel">
<div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger mt-2">
Name is required
</div>
```

And here is the component logic:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-definitions',
  templateUrl: './definitions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./definitions.component.scss']
})
export class DefinitionsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('name', { read: ElementRef }) ingredientName: ElementRef = {} as ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('el', this.ingredientName.nativeElement);
    this.ingredientName.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

However when I load the document the focus doesn't happen. I can see in the console it's logging the element, so that seems to be working.. but the focus isn't.

As I mentioned, this component is being loaded via `ng-content` in it's parent component. I wonder if this is affecting the behaviour, but I can't figure out why it would?

I've also tried using `setTimeout` but that has no effect.

Strangely enough, if I wrap `this.ingredientName.nativeElement.focus()` in a method, and call that method from, say, a button click on the component.. then it works. But not page load.

Anyone have an idea why this doesn't work?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** Okay so it turns out this seems to be a bug with Microsoft Edge. Seems to be working fine in Chrome

Comment: If you add some delay to setTimeout  is it working?

Comment: No I tried that and it didn't work either

Comment: Use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mintplayer/ng-focus-on-load) ([source code](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs%2Fmintplayer-ng-focus-on-load%2Fsrc%2Flib) / [demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/advanced/autofocus)). You can apply the `autofocus` attribute to `<input>`, `<textarea>` and components that implement the `focus` method.

Answer (score -2):

Try using tabindex="0"

```
<input tabindex="0"
     type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
     required
     [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
     #name="ngModel">
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work